# How to use a WP_Customize_Control outside of the Customizer?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, theme-customizer

I have a few custom `WP_Customize_Control` classes that are shown within the standard WordPress Customizer area. These are working fine.

Is it possible to pull some of these out of the customizer and show them in a dedicated plugin page?

I don't need the live preview etc.. just need the customizer element to function and run the sanitize_callback and save any changed settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is possible, but it hasn't been tried before, as far as I know. You would need to instantiate the `WP_Customize_Manager` but likely do some unhooking/rehooking of some of the methods.

Comment: Cheers. It was just quicker to re-create the controls I needed stand alone without the Customize classes. Maybe next project I'll have more time to play with re-using the code.